# class Session in phalcon

Tags: php, session, frameworks, phalcon

I have a question for you related to the framework Falcon. Do you run a class session? I it does not work, I add it to di container and set, and setShared not help. The session does not start, the method writes isStarted false, although the global array $ _SESSION works. What could it be? Help please. I do not know English, so this text is translated by google transition

Comment: It works fine in Phalcon ... show your code ...

Comment: http://pastebin.ru/1cdMyJ5N